# How to plot a sunburst plot in a loop in a RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, sunburst-diagram

My goal is to create an HTML R Markdown report, where I would like to incorporate multiple sunburst graphs, one per entity of my interest. The sunbursts are drawn using `sunburstR` [library](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR). Every graph should be in its respective tab.

The problem is that I have no clue on how to actually display a graph in a tab. I've tried assigning the graph to a variable and `print`ing or `plot`ting it, but to no avail. I've also tried skipping the assignment and doing something with the call for the object, also without success. As sunburstR object is also a `htmlwidget` I've looked also in the manual for this package, but even there I couldn't find a helping hand. The problem seems to be that I am doing it in a loop and to achieve my goal I need to run the code within a cell marked as `results='asis'`, which hinders the displaying of the graph.

The problem below is a bit simplistic, but perfectly shows what I am struggling with (example is a modified version of: https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/blob/master/inst/examples/example_calendar.R). A self-sustainable piece of markdown code to reproduce the issue (please note that everything below is an R Markdown file (.Rmd extension) and it should be run like that):

---

````
---
title: "Markdown with sunburst graphs - example"
author: "User"
date: "`r paste('Date: ', Sys.Date())`"
output: html_document
---

```{r load-packages, include=FALSE}
library(sunburstR)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
```

```{r data-preparation}
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(
    as.Date('2014-01-01'),
    as.Date('2016-12-31'),
    by = "days"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df$year = format(df$date, "%Y")
df$quarter = paste0("Q", ceiling(as.numeric(format(df$date,"%m"))/3))
df$month = format(df$date, "%b")
df$count = rep(1, nrow(df))
```

# Graphs per year {.tabset .tabset-fade #results}

```{r plot-per-year, results='asis'}
for(year_ in unique(df$year)){
  cat(paste0("## ", year_, "\n\n"))
  df_year <- df %>% filter(year == year_) %>% mutate(path=paste(quarter, month, sep="-"))
  print(kable(head(df_year, 5), format="markdown"))
  sunburst(data.frame(xtabs(count~path,df_year))) # what to do here to display the graph?
}
```
````

---

I've also comprised a `kable` object for reference, as it is something that is actually visible in the document opened in a browser (sunburst graph is not). Do you have any suggestion on how to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little messy and not optimized, but should provide a solution. In general, the solution to create `htmlwidgets` in a loop is to `tagList(lapply(... create htmlwidget... )` as described in [DT issue](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/67).  However, since we are trying to wrap each chart in tabs, the solution gets messy.  We will need to manually create the tabs, and then separately create the charts as tab content.

````
---
title: "Markdown with sunburst graphs - example"
author: "User"
date: "`r paste('Date: ', Sys.Date())`"
output: 
  html_document: 
    keep_md: yes
    self_contained: no
---

```{r load-packages, include=FALSE}
library(sunburstR)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(htmltools)
```

```{r data-preparation}
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(
    as.Date('2014-01-01'),
    as.Date('2016-12-31'),
    by = "days"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df$year = format(df$date, "%Y")
df$quarter = paste0("Q", ceiling(as.numeric(format(df$date,"%m"))/3))
df$month = format(df$date, "%b")
df$count = rep(1, nrow(df))
```

# Graphs per year

```{r tabs-per-year, results='asis', warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::tags$ul(
  class = "nav nav-pills",
  role = "tablist",
  lapply(unique(df$year), function(year_) {
    if(year_ == unique(df$year)[1]) {
      class = "active"
    } else {
      class = ""
    }
    htmltools::tags$li(
      role = "presentation",
      class = class,
      htmltools::tags$a(
        role="tab",
        "data-toggle" = "tab",
        href = paste0("#", "year-", year_),
        year_
      )
    )
  })
)
```

```{r charts-per-year, results='asis', warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::tags$div(
  class = "tab-content",
  lapply(unique(df$year), function(year_) {
    if(year_ == unique(df$year[1])) {
      class = "active in"
    } else {
      class = ""
    }
    df_year <- df %>% filter(year == year_) %>% mutate(path=paste(quarter, month, sep="-"))
    htmltools::tags$div(
      id = paste0("year-", year_),
      role = "tabpanel",
      class = paste0("tab-pane tabbed-pane fade ", class),
      sunburst(data.frame(xtabs(count~path,df_year))) # what to do here to display the graph?
    )
  })
)  
```
````